# Magento2 Custom content div

Tags: xml, magento2

I'm trying to add a banner to all my pages.

So i created this:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="banner" template="banner.phtml"/>
```

inside

> default.xml

Which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

  <!--   the banner  -->   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="banner" template="banner.phtml"/>

        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">250</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

So my question is, where do i make the actual banner. Where do i add my custom html, like i cannot find where its located at all do i have to create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I think I helped you out on this one already, but here you go.

follow this folders paths:

```
app/code/YouTheme/Banners/view/frontend/templates/banner.phtml
```

`YouTheme/Banners` are folders from your custom module... Let say Kevin/Banners or whatever you'd like to use. 
banner.phtml is where your custom html code goes.

Remember to clean cache and sometimes run using shell

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Yes, you helped me last day, but the path app/code/YouTheme/Banners/view/frontend/templates/banner.phtml

does not exist, do i have to create this?

Comment: Yes, create all those folders in that order for you to be able to create your own module. You have to create others files too tho. Check this out http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_adding_frontend_files_to_your_module/